# How can I unbind [left-fringe mouse-1] key?

Tags: emacs

I am using GNU Emacs 24.2. Clicking on left fringe sets current line on click line.
I don't want change current line, so I need to unbind this key. I added this in my .emacs file>

```
 (global-unset-key [left-fringe mouse-1])
```

But this don't works.
Running "C-h b" (describe binding) it still show:

[left-fringe mouse-1] mouse--strip-first-event

How can I unbind this key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding of [left-fringe mouse-1] to `mouse--strip-first-event` is not in the map that binds keys to commands because `mouse--strip-first-event` is not a command (instead, it's a remapping function that rewrites the key sequence to something else, in this case it just strips off the first event so that you end up running whatever is bound to [mouse-1]).

This binding is in `function-key-map`, so you can eliminate it with

```
(define-key function-key-map [left-fringe mouse-1] nil)
```

But note also that remappings defined in `function-key-map` only apply when there's no binding to the current event sequence, so you don't really need to remove it: just add a binding (via `global-set-key`) for `[left-fringe mouse-1]` and the above remapping will simply be ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan, it's exactly what I need.